# How to consume https wcf service?

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, ssl, soap

There is a https wcf service I need to consume. Its url is like: https://www.abxyz.com:8082/MasterPassPspUi/PspUiService.svc

I have created a project and configured web.config like:

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IPspUiService"
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="https://www.abxyz.com:8082/MasterPassPspUi/PspUiService.svc"
            binding="basicHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IPspUiService"
            contract="PspUiService.IPspUiService" 
            behaviorConfiguration="SoapInspector" 
            name="BasicHttpBinding_IPspUiService" />
</client>
```

When I call the service it returns

> There was no endpoint listening at
>   https://www.abxyz.com:8082/MasterPassPspUi/PspUiService.svc that could
>   accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or
>   SOAP action.

When I change url to dns address like:

https:/212.2.245.34:8082/MasterPassPspUi/PspUiService.svc

> Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel
>   with authority '212.2.245.34:8082'

Actually I can access the service using web browser, but could you please help me how can I consume this wcf service over https.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first error it looks like you can’t connect the service, with the name. Can you open the address https://www.abxyz.com:8082/MasterPassPspUi/PspUiService.svc in your browser? If you can’t open but you can open https:/212.2.245.34:8082/MasterPassPspUi/PspUiService.svc adress, then I think it is a problem with the system configuration. Is it the right domain?

By the second error, you come on the server, but you get a security error. Do you have a valid certificate in your IIS?  - You can call a web service with a not valid certificate, if the IIS and the client are on the same server. -